# @username: how it works user mentioning?

Tags: discussion

About half of the times I tried to mention a user with `@username` no popup show at all with following impossibility to report its name in my comments or answers.

Is there a bug of platform or I didn't understand how to use this functionality?

Comment: Read through [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) first.